# CUPS error log is quickly filling up

Tags: linux, centos, cups

The printer logs are filling up fast and I have changed the LogLevel to try reduce the rate it is growing.

```
# Log general information in error_log - change "warn" to "debug"
# for troubleshooting...
LogLevel warn
LogDebugHistory 5

# Administrator user group...
SystemGroup sys root

# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
Listen 192.168.2.10:631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
ServerName  nr1.internal.johnsonmg.com
ServerAlias nr1.internal.johnsonmg.com
```

What is causing the log to fill up so quickly? I noticed there are clients in the entries. How do I determine who the clients are?

Is there a guide or documentation that details on how analyse and diagnose the CUPS error log? I can't find any good source of information.

```
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] 1.1 Get-Notifications 1637351
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdProcessIPPRequest(0x563d3cd23840[14]): operation_id = 001c
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] Get-Notifications /printers/
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] get_notifications(con=0x563d3cd23840[14])
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindPolicyOp(p=0x563d3cb64720, op=1c(Get-Notifications))
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindPolicyOp: Found exact match...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: con->uri="/", con->best=0x563d3cb65940((null))
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: owner="prtit2"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: level=CUPSD_AUTH_USER, type=None, satisfy=CUPSD_AUTH_SATISFY_ALL, num_names=2
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: op=1c(Get-Notifications)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: auth=CUPSD_AUTH_ALLOW...
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: requesting-user-name="prtit2"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: Checking user membership...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] copy_attrs(to=0x563d3cc88f20, from=0x563d3cc3c0d0, ra=(nil), group=7, quickcopy=0)
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Notifications (/printers/) from localhost
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdProcessIPPRequest: ippLength(response)=559
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=14, read_cb=0x563d3ac83e00, write_cb=0x563d3ac836e0, data=0x563d3cd23840)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=375, response=0x5
63d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=551, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=559, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_IDLE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=344, response=0x5
63d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=522, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=551, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=313, response=0x5
63d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=485, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=522, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=264, response=0x5
63d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=457, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=485, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=240, response=0x5
63d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=433, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=457, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=192, response=0x5
63d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=408, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=433, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=108, response=0x5
63d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=375, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=408, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=84, response=0x56
3d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=344, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=375, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=62, response=0x56
3d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=313, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=344, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 23] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=32, response=0x56
3d3cc1d8c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=23, read_cb=0x563d3ac83e00, write_cb=(nil), data=0x563d3cd0a5f0)
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=264, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=313, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=240, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=264, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=192, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=240, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=108, response=0x5
63d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=192, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=84, response=0x56
3d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=108, response=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=62, response=0x56
3d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=84, response=0x56
3d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=32, response=0x56
3d3cc9cec0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=19, read_cb=0x563d3ac83e00, write_cb=(nil), data=0x563d3cd063f0)
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=62, response=0x56
3d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 14] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=32, response=0x56
3d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=14, read_cb=0x563d3ac83e00, write_cb=(nil), data=0x563d3cd23840)
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(),
file=-1
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] POST / HTTP/1.1
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: uri = "/"...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: Location /admin/conf Limit 7f
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: Location /admin Limit 7f
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: Location / Limit 7f
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: best = /
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] con->uri="/", con->best=0x563d3cb63660(/)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] Authorization=""
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] No authentication data provided.
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: con->uri="/", con->best=0x563d3cb63660(/)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: level=CUPSD_AUTH_ANON, type=None, satisfy=CUPSD_AUTH_SATISFY_ALL, num_names=0
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: auth=CUPSD_AUTH_ALLOW...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=204, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=204, request=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=175, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=175, request=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=138, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=138, request=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=109, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=109, request=0x5
63d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=77, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=77, request=0x563
d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=51, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=51, request=0x563
d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=33, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=33, request=0x563
d3cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=1, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=1, request=0x563d3
cc88f20(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] 1.1 Get-Notifications 4202060
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdProcessIPPRequest(0x563d3cd021f0[21]): operation_id = 001c
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] Get-Notifications /printers/
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] get_notifications(con=0x563d3cd021f0[21])
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindPolicyOp(p=0x563d3cb64720, op=1c(Get-Notifications))
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindPolicyOp: Found exact match...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: con->uri="/", con->best=0x563d3cb65940((null))
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: owner="pick"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: level=CUPSD_AUTH_USER, type=None, satisfy=CUPSD_AUTH_SATISFY_ALL, num_names=2
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: op=1c(Get-Notifications)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: auth=CUPSD_AUTH_ALLOW...
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: requesting-user-name="pick"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: Checking user membership...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] copy_attrs(to=0x563d3cbe5b50, from=0x563d3cce5150, ra=(nil), group=7, quickcopy=0)
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] Returning IPP successful-ok for Get-Notifications (/printers/) from localhost
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdProcessIPPRequest: ippLength(response)=559
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=21, read_cb=0x563d3ac83e00, write_cb=0x563d3ac836e0, data=0x563d3cd021f0)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout(0): 31 seconds to write dirty config/state files
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=559, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_IDLE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=551, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=522, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=485, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=457, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=433, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=408, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=375, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=344, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=313, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=264, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=240, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=192, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=108, response=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=84, response=0x56
3d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=62, response=0x56
3d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=32, response=0x56
3d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdAddSelect(fd=21, read_cb=0x563d3ac83e00, write_cb=(nil), data=0x563d3cd021f0)
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_WAITING, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=0, request=(nil)(),
file=-1
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] POST / HTTP/1.1
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients, printing jobs, and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: uri = "/"...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: Location /admin/conf Limit 7f
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: Location /admin Limit 7f
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: Location / Limit 7f
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdFindBest: best = /
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] con->uri="/", con->best=0x563d3cb63660(/)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] Authorization=""
D [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] No authentication data provided.
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: con->uri="/", con->best=0x563d3cb63660(/)
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: level=CUPSD_AUTH_ANON, type=None, satisfy=CUPSD_AUTH_SATISFY_ALL, num_names=0
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] cupsdIsAuthorized: auth=CUPSD_AUTH_ALLOW...
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=627, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=627, request=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=598, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=598, request=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=561, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=561, request=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=518, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=518, request=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=503, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=503, request=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=480, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=480, request=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1681341497
d [12/Apr/2023:12:04:30 +1000] [Client 21] cupsdReadClient error=0, used=457, state=HTTP_POST_RECV, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=457, request=0x5
63d3cbe5b50(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), file=-1
```

Comment: That's definitely a debug log - see the `d` and `D` in the beginning of the lines. That level will fill up any log as it outputs absolutely everything - that's why it's only used for troubleshooting. If the server's log level is set to `warn`, something's failing in the server.

Comment: I have set it to warn but it is displaying debug information. I believe warn also logs debug  information in some cases.

Comment: Possible, tho' I've never bumped into such a situation. Do you actually have problems with printing? If you drop the level to "Error" do you still see debug messages? How about if you increase it from "Error" back to "Warning"?